# rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node error while loading shared libraries

Tags: ros, turtlesim, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i'm trying to learn ROS and I am following the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/it/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes.
When I reach part 1.7 I use rosrun but it returns an error:

```
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using the Ubuntu app (version 2004.2021.222.0) for Windows 10 (version 2004 build SO 19041.508) with Noetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381325/rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node-error-while-loading-shared-libraries/) by [Simone Diomede](https://answers.ros.org/users/76830/simone-diomede/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AmirSaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/64433/amirsaman/) on 2021-06-29**:
Hi Simone, just to clarify you are running Ubuntu OS 20.04 on a virtualizer such as Oracle VM VirtualBox or vmware workstation and you managed to install ROS Neotic sucsessfully and when you are running

`roscd turtlesim`

in terminal you will be directed to the package location right ?

Have you seen this [link](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4497) ?

they used

```
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so
```

and managed to solve the problem

**Comment by [Simone Diomede](https://answers.ros.org/users/76830/simone-diomede/) on 2021-06-29**:
Yes, thank you.
That sudo command solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3023) related to this on WSL GitHub. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61739001/7589046) mentions the steps that should solve the problem. Run them with `sudo` inside your Ubuntu environment.

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61739001/7589046) as well, `sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5` seems to have solved the issue.

---

Originally posted by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) with karma: 156 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Simone Diomede](https://answers.ros.org/users/76830/simone-diomede/) on 2021-06-29**:
The sudo command worked for me, thank you.